# How to limit "docker history" output to a reasonable column size?

Tags: docker

I am using the `docker history` command to analyze the size of a docker container.

It's great, it allows to see each command that was called to create a layer and how much space it took.

Problem: The output is truncated. I can't see which file is copied or which package is yum installed because it's truncated.

```
$ docker history <container>
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c mkdir -p /data/app/configuration/...       0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:812d65baaf75c0d2e...   176B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5654e404129f15820...   534B
<missing>      2 months ago    |0 /bin/sh -c yum install -y postgresql post...   40.1MB
```

I know that can pass the `--no-trunc` flat to disable truncation however it doesn't help with readability. Some lines are very long (yum install too many packages) and the output with `--no-trunc` is difficult to read.

Is it possible to adjust the formatting to show the full command up to a reasonable size?

Answer (score 1):

Magical incantation to limit the command length to 160 characters when using `docker history`:

```
 docker history --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Size}}\t{{.CreatedSince}}\\t{{truncate .CreatedBy 160 }}" <image>
```

Comment: Your command gives an error when run. Take better care when copy pasting. It should be `docker history --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Size}}\t{{.CreatedSince}}\\t{{truncate .CreatedBy 160 }}" <image>`. I.e. `--format` should only be there once and `<image>` should be outside the quotes.